# Combine ContainerID row and add Qty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to combine Container ID, Date, and add the Qty. This query shows data at the item level. I want it to print data at the order level and sum the "Qty" column.

I can combine rows using excel & pivot tables, but when I run reports for over 3 months, I run out of rows in excel, so I break it up into smaller chunks and add the results. Tedious. There has to be an easier way.

What I am getting:

```
OrderDate   ContainerID Qty
2019-06-03  104922434   1
2019-06-03  104922434   1
2019-06-01  104934958   1
2019-06-01  104934958   1
2019-06-01  104934958   1
```

What I want:

```
OrderDate   ContainerID Qty
2019-06-03  104922434   2
2019-06-01  104934958   3
```

My current query:

```
select     

convert(date,oh.ShipTime) as 'OrderDate',
p.ContainerID,
cc.Qty

from dmhost.tblOrderHeader oh

join dmhost.tblContainer c on oh.OrderHeaderID = c.OrderHeaderID
join dmhost.tblPackage p on c.ContainerID = p.ContainerID
join dmhost.tblContainerContents cc on c.ContainerID = cc.ContainerID
join dmhost.tblItemMaster im on im.ItemMasterID = cc.ItemMasterID

where (oh.ShipTime between '06/1/2019' and '07/1/2019')
and (BusinessUnitCode like '03'or BusinessUnitCode like '04')
and cc.Qty <> 0

order by p.ContainerID
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you asking how to `SUM`?

Comment: [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Can you show me how I can input this in my current query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select     

convert(date,oh.ShipTime) as 'OrderDate',
p.ContainerID,
SUM(cc.Qty) Qty

from dmhost.tblOrderHeader oh

join dmhost.tblContainer c on oh.OrderHeaderID = c.OrderHeaderID
join dmhost.tblPackage p on c.ContainerID = p.ContainerID
join dmhost.tblContainerContents cc on c.ContainerID = cc.ContainerID
join dmhost.tblItemMaster im on im.ItemMasterID = cc.ItemMasterID

where (oh.ShipTime between '06/1/2019' and '07/1/2019')
and (BusinessUnitCode like '03'or BusinessUnitCode like '04')
and cc.Qty <> 0

group by
    convert(date,oh.ShipTime),
    p.ContainerID

order by ContainerID
```

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly. Thank you much!